# How can I switch windows on a timed basis

Tags: windows-7, switch, timer

I would like to have one window maximized for X minutes, then have it switch to another window ad infinitum (Windows 7/2008 R2).  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of using something like [AutoHotKeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or more likely [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) scripts to send keystrokes like ALT+TAB on a scheduled basis.

Whilst looking for an AutoIt script to do this, I found a VBS which does the job, courtesy of [Spinner Software](http://www.spinnersoftware.com/kb/en/scripting/switch_between_windows.html).